# My item in my list vie not shown

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am wondering how to show my data from list to my listview, but when I try I get blank screen:

```
    for(int i=0;i<Kolomlistview.Count;i++)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add(Kolomlistview[i]);
    }
    int j = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<KodeBarang.Count;i++)
    {
        string[] row = { j.ToString(), KodeBarang[i] };
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        Controls.Add(listView1);
        j++;
    }
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

Screen:

[image]

Comment: You are not using the data in `row` in the listview item.

Comment: Why are you adding `listView1` to the control collection many times? Why are you adding it in the first place? Are you creating it dynamically?

Comment: @YacoubMassad oowh i see my bad , thank you sir